# Infinite Do...while loop using Async Await

Tags: c#, async-await

I have following code:

```
public static async Task<string> ReadLineAsync(this Stream stream, Encoding encoding)
{
byte[] byteArray = null;
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
   int bytesRead= 0;
   do
   {
       byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
       try
       {
             bytesRead = await stream.ReadAsync(buf, 0, 1024);
             await ms.WriteAsync(buf, 0, bytesRead);
       }
       catch (Exception e)
       {
             Console.WriteLine(e.Message + e.StackTrace);
       }
   } while (stream.CanRead && bytesRead> 0);

   byteArray = ms.ToArray();
   return encoding.GetString(ms.ToArray());
}
```

I am trying to read `Stream` to write into `MemoryStream` asynchronously, but the `Do...while` loop is failing to break. I mean it's an infinite loop. How to solve this?

Comment: Have you tried it in a debugger?

Comment: Are you calling `Wait` or `Result` on the task generated from this method in a UI context?  If so, that'll cause a deadlock.

Comment: are you reading the first 1024 bytes of the stream every time and not moving to the next set of bytes?

Comment: @BobKaufman While debugging, the loop control just vanishes after 2 times. Don't knnow what is happening.

Comment: I am wondering why you think the read itself needs to be async, when you're returning a Task in your method body anyway.  You will already be `await`ing from the outside of the method, in other words.

Comment: @JohnBoker I think the function `ReadAsync()` handles it for us

Comment: Not a direct answer but you might be find the [Stream.CopyToAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.copytoasync.aspx) method useful here. (Target framework has to be .NET 4.5)

Comment: @BhushanFirake ok just making sure.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I want to have both operatins async in a multi-tenant app

Comment: Do you really need the `Read` & `Write` async methods?  You have await so they are synchrous so it doesn't make much sense.  Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Justin So, you are saying that keeping `await` on both of them will make them synchronous? Nope not true...

Comment: is your Catch getting an exception?

Comment: @Servy I am not calling `Result` or `Wait`, but still curious to know how will it cause deadlock?

Comment: @Sayse Nope..nothing caught, as said earlier, for first time `bytesRead=1`, then `bytesRead=51` then boom...control vanishes..

Comment: @BhushanFirake If you're doing a blocking wait in the UI thread then the UI thread won't be able to do anything until this task completes.  The callbacks generated from the `await` calls need to run in the UI thread, but the UI thread won't be able to run it since something else is running (the code doing the blocking wait).  You now have two things each waiting on each other and no progress being made, thus, deadlock.

Comment: @Servy Ohh..ok no UI thread or something like that here.

Comment: @keyboardP Same with that method too..

Comment: Can you show your calling code? I'm able to run this with a trivial caller without issue in and out of the debugger.

Comment: @BhushanFirake There shouldn't be a `do...while` loop with that method. Are you saying that it never returns from the `CopyToAsync` call?

Comment: @keyboardP For `CopyToAsync`, I removed the Do...while loop...and still it is not returning...

Comment: @BhushanFirake Try a different, smaller, stream and see if the input stream itself is causing the problem.

Comment: @keyboardP My stream is nothing more than just a stream from IMAP client

Comment: @PrestonGuillot Here you go `protected async Task<string> GetResponseAsync()
        {
            return await Stream.ReadLineAsync(Encoding, null);
        }`

Comment: @PrestonGuillot My encoding is: `Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);`

Comment: If bytesRead is never becoming zero, what is being copied to your buffer?

Comment: @Yogee `52` bytes only as discussed in comments

Answer (score 5):

First, in an exceptional situation, your loop would continue indefinitely. You shouldn't catch and ignore exceptions.

Secondly, if the stream doesn't actually *end*, then `bytesRead` would never be zero. I suspect this is the case because the name of the method (`ReadLineAsync`) doesn't imply to me that it will read until the end of the stream.

P.S. `CanRead` does not ever change for a specific stream. It's whether it makes semantic sense for a stream to do a read operation, not whether it can read *right now*.

Comment: Ohh but my stream ends in finite time.

Comment: Then please post a minimal repro.

Comment: Are you *absolutely* sure your stream is *ending*? IMAP connections are usually kept for multiple commands and responses.

Comment: Can you comment about `Encoding`? I am using `Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);` in the calling function

Comment: Since the `while` doesn't exit, the encoding won't be used.

Answer (score 0):

You have your loop condition set to run as long as CanRead is true and bytesRead is greater then 0. CanRead will always be true if your file is readable. This means as long as you start reading your bytes will always be greater than zero. You need to have a maximum number of bytes to be read as well as a minimum or set some other control to break out.

Comment: I think Stream.CanRead is for that purpose only. We don't have to do it manually

Answer (score 0):

I took your method and modified it just a tad by shortening the read buffer size and adding some debug statements

```
    public static async Task<string> ReadLineAsync(this Stream stream, Encoding encoding)
    {
        const int count = 2;
        byte[] byteArray = Enumerable.Empty<byte>().ToArray();
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            int bytesRead = 0;
            do
            {
                byte[] buf = new byte[count];
                try
                {
                    bytesRead = await stream.ReadAsync(buf, 0, count);
                    await ms.WriteAsync(buf, 0, bytesRead);
                    Console.WriteLine("{0:ffffff}:{1}:{2}",DateTime.Now, stream.CanRead, bytesRead);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message + e.StackTrace);
                }
            } while (stream.CanRead && bytesRead > 0);

            byteArray = ms.ToArray();
            return encoding.GetString(byteArray);
        }
    }
```

but basically it worked as expected with the following call:

```
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(@"C:\in.txt");
        Encoding encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);
        Task<string> result = stream.ReadLineAsync(encoding);
        result.ContinueWith(o =>
            {
                Console.Write(o.Result);
                stream.Dispose();
            });

        Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to continue...");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

so I'm wondering could it be something with your input file? Mine was (encoded in Windows-1252 in Notepad++)

```
one
two
three
```

and my output was

```
Press ENTER to continue...
869993:True:2
875993:True:2
875993:True:2
875993:True:2
875993:True:2
875993:True:2
875993:True:2
875993:True:1
875993:True:0
one
two
three
```

note how the "Press ENTER to continue..." was printed first as expected because the main method was invoked asynchronously, and `CanRead` is always true because it means the file is readable. Its the state of how the file was opened, not the state meaning that the cursor is at the EOF.

Comment: As specified in the comments above, my encoding is `Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);`

Comment: Ok I tried with Windows-1252. Still got expected result. You say you are trying to read a stream, is that from a file? or something like a web request?

Comment: You should add some code as to how you get the IMAP stream and what libraries you are using. Sounds like whatever stream you are getting is not ending, like in the simple file example.

Answer (score 0):

So, you are taking a stream from IMAP and this method is for converting that steam into text?
Why not construct a SteamReader round the stream and call either it's ReadToEndAsync or just ReadToEnd?  I doubt the need for making this an Async operation, if the stream is something like an e-mail then it is unlikely to be so big that a user will notice the UI blocking while it reads.
If, as one of your comments suggests, this isn't a UI app at all then it is probably even less of an issue.

If my assumptions are wrong then could I ask you to update your question with some more information about how this function is being used.  The more information you can tell us, the better our answers can be.

EDIT:
I just noticed that your method is called ReadLineAsync, although I can't see anywhere in the code that you are looking for a line ending.  If your intention is to read a line of text then the SteamReader also provides ReadLine and ReadLineAsync.

Comment: Actually, this code is used in a multi-tenant app for sake of speed and asynchrony, wherein we are taking a stream from IMAP and this method is for converting that stream to a string with given encoding `Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);`.

Comment: Async doesnt necessarily mean faster. I dont really understand what you mean by a multi-tennant app. Is this some sort of server component? If so, then the thread pool may provide a better means of scaling this operation.

Answer (score 0):

From my POV, looks like your code is trying to do the following:

- read an entire stream as a sequence of 1024-octet chunks,
- concatenate all those chunks into a `MemoryStream` (which uses a byte array as its backing store),
- convert the MemoryStream to a string using the specified encoding
- return that string to the caller.

This seems...complicated to me. Maybe I'm missing something, but to use `async` and `await`, you've got to be using VS2012 and .Net 4.5, or VS2010. .Net 4.0 and the Async CTP, right? If so, why wouldn't you simply use a `StreamReader` and its `StreamReader.ReadToEndAsync()` method?

```
public static async Task<string> MyReadLineAsync(this Stream stream, Encoding encoding)
{
  using ( StreamReader reader = new StreamReader( stream , encoding ) )
  {
    return await reader.ReadToEndAsync() ;
  }
}
```

The overlapping i/o idea is nice, but the time required to write to a memory stream is, to say the least, not enough to make one whit of difference with respect to the time required to peform actual I/O (presumably your input stream is doing disk or network i/o).

Comment: Your code won't compile. Did you mean `return await reader.ReadToEndAsync();`?

Comment: Why did this get 3 downvotes? There is nothing wrong with this answer besides a simple compile error (which I took the liberty of fixing)

Comment: @IsakSavo The way you fixed it is wrong. This way, `reader` is going to be `Dispose()`d before `ReadToEndAsync()` actually completes. So the compile error is not that simple.